# I want to make a hour glass out of the 2D array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sub-array

I am trying to form an hour glass of this 2D array

1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 2 4 4 0
0 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 1 2 4 0

I want to make all the possible hour glass out to this 2D list which looks like this:
[image]

and print the sum of each hour glass

Note: I am using python3

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import turtle as trt
import numpy as np
import math

Width, Height = 700, 700
trt ._CFG['width'],  trt ._CFG['height'] = Width *1.02,  Height *1.02  ##  no scrollbars
trt ._CFG['canvwidth'],  trt ._CFG['canvheight'] = Width, Height  ##  no external turtle.cfg required

turtle, screen = trt .Turtle(),  trt .Screen()
screen .setworldcoordinates( 0, Height, Width, 0 )
screen .title( 'Hourglass' )

screen .tracer( 42, 0 )  ##  nth screen draw, delay
scale = math .sqrt( Width *Width + Height *Height ) *0.5
padding = ( max( Width, Height ) -scale )

screen .colormode( 1 )  ##  range 0-1,  defaults 0-255

array = np .array( [ [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
                     [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
                     [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
                     [ 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0 ],
                     [ 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 ],
                     [ 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0 ] ] )

turtle .penup()
turtle .shapesize( 4 )
turtle .shape( 'circle' )
for y in range( len( array ) ):
    for x in range( len( array[y] ) ):
        current_pos = array[y][x]
        if current_pos > 0:
            if current_pos > 2:  turtle. color( 'red' )
            elif current_pos > 1:  turtle. color( 'blue' )
            else:                   turtle. color( 'black' )
            turtle .goto( x *scale /6 +padding,  y *scale /6 +padding /2 )
            turtle .stamp()


screen .update()  ##  for tracer
screen .listen()  ##  for mouse & key presses
screen .exitonclick()  ##  binds .bye() to screen click
screen .mainloop()
```

[image: Hourglass]

Comment: I edited the question can you check it out again?